# How to accurately split and combine videos with ffmpeg respecting inpoint/outpoint

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, mpeg4

I'm learning how to split and combine videos with `ffmpeg`. Presently I'm practicing on a 799 KB MP4, [`one_through_ten-timestamped.mp4`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01AJq-CMtNMZzJpQTZPQWVuMk0/view?usp=sharing), where each frame has a burnt-in "frame number" (up to frame 40, the burnt-in number advances only every other frame).

The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i one_through_ten_edit_list.txt -c copy one_through_ten_edited.mp4
```

Where `one_through_ten_edit_list.txt` is:

```
file one_through_ten-timestamped.mp4
inpoint 00:00:01.500
outpoint 00:00:05.000
file one_through_ten-timestamped.mp4
inpoint 00:00:09.500
outpoint 00:00:13.000
```

When I perform this command in `ffmpeg` the output video has several issues:

1. The output starts from the beginning of the source video instead of 1.5 s in.
2. The audio after the second input video is concatenated is delayed (when played on QuickTime Player. It's fine on `ffplay`).

When I perform these same edits in [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com), the resulting video plays as expected. Here's some tabular output from `ffprobe` on `one_through_ten-timestamped.mp4` which shows where the ffmpeg video and MPEG Streamclip differ in their concatenation points:

[image: start of first segment]
[image: end of first segment]
[image: mpeg streamclip start 1st]
[image: start of second segments]
[image: end of second segment]

Notice that both `ffmpeg` and MPEG Streamclip handle the second segment roughly the same, however `ffmpeg` doesn't seem to respect the `inpoint` in the first input video. Note that in my MP4, there's one packet per frame.

`ffmpeg` has behaved this way from version 2.8 (perhaps before) up through 3.3.3. Am I missing a command-line or edit-list option? Surely others have been successfully using `ffmpeg` to split and combine videos (without recompressing).

Comment: From the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat): "inpoint–This directive works best with intra frame codecs, because for non-intra frame ones you will usually get extra packets before the actual In point and the decoded content will most likely contain frames before In point too."

Comment: What did you end up doing OP?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `-async 1`

```
ffmpeg -f concat -async 1 -safe 0 -i one_through_ten_edit_list.txt -c copy one_through_ten_edited.mp4
```