# How to get exact timecode splitting using ffmpeg commands

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I have a file called `ffmpeg.cmd` which has inpoints and outpoints.

```
file 'testA.webm'
inpoint 00:02:11.032
outpoint 00:02:36.900
file 'testA.webm'
inpoint 00:09:06.100
outpoint 00:09:43.799
```

If I run `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -async 1 -i ffmpeg.cmd out.mp4` I do not get precise cuts. They can be a second or more off. I found [another question about this which suggested setting async to 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1250147/how-to-accurately-split-and-combine-videos-with-ffmpeg-respecting-inpoint-outpoi), but I couldn't get that to work either.

I tried converting the original webm to mp4 (going from VP9 to h264) and I still had the same issue. Is there a certain codec my source video needs to be in order for ffmpeg to make percise cuts, or another argument I need on the command line?

Comment: you can convert testA.webm to huffyuv format `ffmpeg -i "testA.webm" -c:v huffyuv -c:a pcm_s16le -y "testA.mkv"` where every frame is keyframe